# Logging in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

We have a custom logger created with winston npm for our nodejs applications. In this custom logger, we will create a logging location with the following piece of code.

```
const LOG_LOCATION = `${__dirname}/../logs`;
if (!fs.existsSync(LOG_LOCATION)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(LOG_LOCATION);
}
```

I'm just wondering whether the log location creation will work in a server-less environment (lambda)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **will not work** in lambda. Since the **only writable location** in Lambda is **/tmp**. Rest of the directories are read-only.

Logging is automatically taken care of sending them to Cloudwatch which is a log distributed system.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Javascript & Node.js in AWS Lambda, you should use the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) object.

Some examples:

```js
console.log('A custom log message here')

try {
  something_will_go_wrong()
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Lambda platform will automatically pick up everything output to `console` and pipe it to a [CloudWatch Logs Stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Working-with-log-groups-and-streams.html). You can later inspect your logs in CloudWatch console or use a specialized tool like [Dashbird](https://dashbird.io/cloudwatch-aws-lambda/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=qanda&utm_content=aws-lambda) to receive alerts and investigate errors connected to other services used by the Lambda, such as S3 or DynamoDB for example.